# Merge lists with duplicated items which are withing one big list

Tags: python

I need an efficient algorithm to merge lists with duplicated items into 1 list. the lists have the same excat items at different order. and they are all inside one big list. 
example: [ [1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5],[5,4],[6] ]
the output should be: [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]

i have this code but i get index out of range when iterating the list and removing items as i go:

```
biglist = [ [1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5],[5,4],[6] ]

for i in range(len(biglist)):
    temp = set(biglist[i])
    for j in range(i,len(biglist)-1):
        temp2 = set(biglist[j])
        if(temp == temp2):
            del biglist[j]
```

Comment: You need answer in sorted order of lists.

Comment: You delete items from `biglist` while looping over it, so your indices are out of range.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I know. I need a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to sort then convert to tuples the lists inside `biglist`,
`set()` will then allow to remove duplicates.

```
def remove_dups(a):
    return list(map(list, set(map(tuple, map(sorted, a)))))

print (remove_dups(biglist))
# [[4, 5], [6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation is in the code comments.

Try this:

```
big_list = [ [1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5],[5,4],[6] ]
temp_list = []

#for every small list in the big list
for small_list in big_list:
    #sort small list
    small_list.sort()
    #if the small list is not in the temp list, add it
    if small_list not in temp_list:
        temp_list.append(small_list)
        #sort the temp list
        temp_list.sort()
#print the temp list
print (temp_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your own code instead of writing a new one. Hope this might help you to understand what went wrong and solve it.

```
biglist = [ [1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5],[5,4],[6] ]

#list to keep track of the indexes which should be deleted
indexes=[]
for i in range(len(biglist)):
    temp = set(biglist[i])
    for j in range(i+1,len(biglist)):
        temp2 = set(biglist[j])
        if(temp == temp2):
            indexes.append(j)
#to remove the  duplicates
indexes=list(set(indexes))


for i in range (len(indexes)):
    #to delete in reverse order so that indexes won't be affected
    del biglist[indexes[len(indexes)-i-1]]

print biglist
```

Comment: This code will not cover the case where the duplicate is a sub-list of 1 element. Try to add another [6] in the list and you will see that it is included twice. (I won't downvote your answer now, so please try to correct it)

Comment: it was an issue with the range of j. my bad. its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import itertools
biglist = [ [1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3],[4,5],[5,4],[6] ]
sort_l = [sorted(i) for i in biglist]
list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(sort_l))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to sorted `tuples`then use `set` on the list of tuples and convert them back to lists.

```
lst = [i for i in set(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in biglist)]
res = sorted([*i] for i in lst)

print(res)
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: i get invalid syntax at the * in the [*i]. if i remove the * i get output where each list is inside tuple