# How to filter out equivalent lists of values in python?

Tags: python, set

When given a list of lists like: `[[5, 2] [2, 5]]`
I want to reduce this list to this: `[[5, 2]]` or `[[2, 5]]`

I've already tried the following: `list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, parts_to_add))))`
But the problem with this method is that it turns my lists in sets and while this works - it filters out all the equivalent lists - it also eats all of my duplicate values; When given `[[3, 3]]` it returns `[[3]]`, due to the nature of sets in python. Is there another way of doing this?
Any help would be grately appreciated.

Comment: You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of sets

Comment: well, there is the *Paris-to-NewYork-through-Moscow* approach: `[list(x) for x in set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a)]`

Comment: @soon How would you do that with `Counter`?

Comment: Directly replacing frozenset with Counter, gives a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis My bad, they will not work with sets. There is a way to make hashable counter just by freezing it, though I think it is better to just sort inner lists if they are small.

Comment: [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914084/merge-lists-with-duplicated-items-which-are-withing-one-big-list/52914826#52914826)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do :

```
data = [[5, 2], [2, 5], [3, 3]]

result = set(tuple(e) for e in map(sorted, data))

print([list(e) for e in result])
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 5], [3, 3]]
```

As @soon mentioned you could use a *frozen* Counter, for example:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [[5, 2], [2, 5], [3, 3]]
result = [e for e in {frozenset(Counter(e)): e for e in data}.values()]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 5], [3, 3]]
```

The above approach also uses a `dict` for removing duplicates instead of a `set`.

Comment: can condense everything in one line `list(set(map(tuple,map(sorted, data))))`

Comment: Why would you use a `tuple` here Daniel?

Comment: @Trashtalk tuples are hashable, so they can be used in a set.

Comment: Thank you (filler)

Answer (score 2):

A more straightforward approach would be,

```
data = [[2, 5], [5, 2], [3, 6], [2, 5], [6, 3]]
result = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i].sort()
    if data[i] not in result:
        result.append(data[i]) 



In [49]: result
Out[49]: [[2, 5], [3, 6]]
```